# Format of System ID generated based on a Bluetooth Device Address

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

OFFICIAL BLE SPEC STATES: 
If System ID generated based on a Bluetooth Device Address, it is required to be done as follows. System ID and the Bluetooth Device Address have a very similar structure: a Bluetooth Device Address is 48 bits in length and consists of a 24 bit Company Assigned Identifier (manufacturer defined identifier) concatenated with a 24 bit Company Identifier (OUI). In order to encapsulate a Bluetooth Device Address as System ID, the Company Identifier is concatenated with 0xFFFE followed by the Company Assigned Identifier of the Bluetooth Address.

**Question:**
If a device's BDA is *12:34:56:9A:BC:DE*, then what is the correct format for System ID?

*0x123456 FFFE 9ABCDE* or 
*0x563412 FEFF DEBC9A* or
*0xDEBC9A FFFE 563412*

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [details about System ID attribute](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.system_id.xml) on SIG's page ?

Comment: I did. And the example given there is: _If the system ID is based of a Bluetooth Device Address with a Company Identifier (OUI) is 0x123456 and the Company Assigned Identifier is 0x9ABCDE, then the System Identifier is required to be 0x123456FFFE9ABCDE._ However, if you look at the end of the page, it there is a note: _The fields in the above table are in the order of LSO to MSO. Where LSO = Least Significant Octet and MSO = Most Significant Octet._ This note is throwing me off. Does that mean the Company ID & Company Assigned ID needs to be in LSO to MSO?